# Get Dynamic Windows Download Folder Path with Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, path, acrobat

I would like to get the path to the windows download folder of the user. So it needs to be dynamic. I want to store it in a local variable und use it inside Adobe Acrobat Reader.

var filePath = "PATH"

I have tried the following two but unfortunately it did not work

%userprofile%/Downloads

C:\Users%username%\Downloads

This did not work either from Acrobat Reader
var filePath = '"C:\Users" & Environ("UserName") & "\Downloads"'

Comment: If javascript could get or control where files are downloaded to, it would be a security risk. So, no you can't force paths on user via javascript.